# How to feed an array of symbols to delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do something like:

```
project_paths = project_hash.keys
delegate :params, :h, :raw, :link_to, project_paths, to: :@view
```

but `project_paths` is an array, and that doesn't work here.

How can I turn an array of symbols into a "list" of comma separated symbols that I can feed to [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)?

Comment: `project_paths` is an array of symbols, e.g. `[:project_1, :project_2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the splat operator:

```
delegate :params, :h, :raw, :link_to, *project_paths, to: :@view
```